C#. Windows Forms. Мылит форму. 4.8
У меня немного мылит форму на .NET Framework 4.8.
Проверил на .NET 8.0, там всё нормально. Можно ли это как то исправить?

Вот это почитайте, например: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8 Или вот здесь тоже самое вкратце: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50686230/8324991

Вам нужно включить DPI Awareness в манифест приложения, либо просто используйте .NET 8+, а не устаревший .NET Framework 4.8, там всё работает из коробки.
